# getElementById id does not exist

Tags: javascript

I have run into a problem with getElementById again.. I never quite understood the behaviour of this method, as simple as it should be, it often doesn't work for me.

What I have now is a HTML page that contains:

```
<div id="vraag">
    ha
</div>

<div id="antwoorden">

</div>
<div id="controls">
    <form name="controlform">
        <input type="button" name="back" disabled value="<" onClick="goBack();" />
        <input type="button" name="forth" value=">" onClick="goForth();" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I have attached a javascript file that does several (working) things, among which is this:

```
document.getElementById['vraag'].innerHTML = 'ho';
```

However, when I click the button that calls this, the firefox error console says:
`Error: document.getElementById.vraag is undefined`

Sadly, the only think I can think of is.. It simply is! I have used this method in very similar environments and that still works, so I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work..

Comment: Is your javascript file attached in the head or the body of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `( )` instead of `[ ]`

```
document.getElementById("vraag").innerHTML = 'ho';
```

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/QKeHP/

Comment: Dude, I feel stupid! And I was wondering why the syntax highlighting didn't kick in! Looked at dozens of simple examples and never noticed I used the wrong brackets.. Thanks a lot!